# Does any JavaScript file load automatically for index.php file?

Tags: theme-development, javascript

I am definitely newbie to theme development in wordpress and I'm working on a theme developed by others.

I have an `index.php` file with some CSS  and JS file loaded in `header.php` files linked to it in my theme. I'm designing a category pages and I copy-paste exactly the `index.php` file into `category-categoryID.php` file. when I open `mysite.mydomain/category_name` everything is like my first page, except javascripts in the front page.

Any Idea?

Comment: No javascript is automatically loaded for index.php. Are you sure that index.php is being loaded? Maybe front-page.php or home.php? If a page is the homepage, then maybe page.php or singular.php? Have you checked the functions.php (and other php files included from there) to see if any scripts are conditionally loaded on the home page?

Comment: @NathanJohnson Yes I'm sure! I changed `index.php` and see the result in front-page.

Comment: Edit your question to show how you are loading your javascript files.

Comment: I'm not sure (since you didn't add enough related CODE), but it's possible that somewhere in your theme (most likely `functions.php`) JavaScript was added with `is_front_page()` or `is_home()` check.